# Symfony2 one-to-one association bidirectional

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-one

I have to tables in DB: user, profile.
Table profile has a field called user_id.

```
class User {
  ....

  /**
   * @var \MyBundle\Entity\Profile
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user")
   *
   */
  private $profile;

  ....
}
```

And Profile class:

```
class Profile {
      ....

      /**
       * @var \MyBundle\Entity\User
       * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
       *
       */
      private $user;

      ....
    }
```

When I try to get Profile by id and then use `->getUser()` it works fine, but if I get User by id and then want to `->getProfile()` it does not work (return null).

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
            ->find(76322);

$user->getProfile(); // returns null :(

$profile = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Profile')
            ->find(12334);

$profile->getUser(); // return User object
```

Comment: are you sure that the provided ID has a related profile or does it exists?

Comment: What do you have in the function `getProfile`?

Comment: return $this->profile;

Comment: Check your user database table.  profile_id is probably null.  If so then I'll show you how to fix.

Comment: There is user_id in profile table. There is no profile_id in user table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
class User {
  ....

  /**
   * @var \MyBundle\Entity\Profile
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="users")
   *
   */
  private $profiles;

  ....
}
```

Profile class:

```
class Profile {
          ....

          /**
           * @var \MyBundle\Entity\User
           * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profiles")
           *
           */
          private $users;

          ....
        }
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly solved.
I had xml files with entity metadata also. I deleted them. Works fine.